# Grails GSP display Service variable where process time is being calculated

Tags: grails, service, gsp

I'm trying to show on the view a progress of a process that is running within a service. My Controller calls the first service which is sending information to a third party, I'm recording each time this happens by calling the second service that does a calculation to show the percentage of request complete.

I have the value I want updating in the first service but I'm unsure how to update the view with this value. I don't return to the Controller until the job is complete.

first service

```
    def batch(toCalculate,otherStuffDoneTotal otherData) {

        def processPercentage

        toCalculate.eachWithIndex(){ data, i ->

            def otherMethod = otherMethod1(doStuffHere)
            def progress = secondService.progressCalc(otherStuffDone, otherStuffDoneTotal, processPercentage)
            }
     }
```

second service

```
    def progressCalc(otherStuffDoneTotal, otherStuffDone, processPercentage) {

        def retItems
        def retObjs = [:]

        processPercentage = 100 / otherStuffDoneTotal * otherStuffDone

        retItems = [processPercentage: processPercentage]
        retObjs.putAll(retItems)
        return(retOjbs)

    }
```

How do I get the view to dynamically update the value (progress.progressPercentage) from the first service

Answer (score 0):

The task is not that trivial.

You have 3 options here:

1. short polling: create a controller action to return the current percentage, and use an AJAX function to call the action and show the progress in the view.
2. long polling/asynch update. There are a number of frameworks supporting that, in Java world I'd recommend [vertx.io](http://vertx.io/) which provides you with the functionality to update your view as the server's state changes
3. Fake it. Let your javascript pretend to poll the data from the server, and update the percentage at some pace. this solution is far from being perfect, but can be good enough from the POV of user experience

Comment: unfortunately I can't fake it as the processing time depends on the values I'm getting whilst processing. The service is also accessed via different controllers within my application and so I'm trying to keep everything to a minimum. Sounds like the short polling is the way to go, how do I return the value processPercentage whilst still processing the data to a different method in my controller which I can then use AJAX. Or should I create a different controller just for the polling because of multiple uses and not have to replicate the code?

Comment: I suggested the `strategies`. what you are asking for are the `implementation details`.